# Else status in php

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I would need some help, since this code does not work (I have lack of knowledge, but I need to have it in that format)

$user_goals is array()
$user_count is just a number like 15

```
    <?php foreach ($user_goals as $number): ?>
    <?php if ($number < $user_count): ?>
        <h5 class="text-center"><strike><?php echo htmlspecialchars($number); ?> users</strike></h5>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($number); ?> users</h5>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any help will be apreciated :)

result that I want:

```
$user_count = 15;

$user_goals = array(
10,
15,
20,
etc,
);
```

so I want to get:

```
<strike>10</strike><br>
<strike>15</strike><br>
20
```

Comment: Any effort in doing so yourself? What bit does not work?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: you can check my work here... http://i.imgur.com/pPNlAxP.jpg

Comment: @Jim i does not strike text if goal is reached like there is no else statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself

```
    <?php 
    foreach ($user_goals as $number) {
        if ($number <= $users_count) {
         echo "<h5 class='text-center'><strike>$number users</strike></h5>";
        }else{
         echo "<h5 class='text-center'>$number users</h5>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add a strike through when the goal is less than or equal to, you need to use that [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

```
if ($number <= $user_count)
```